Attempting to install Xilinx can driver in Linux kernel. It seems I am having dependency issues
I am using Linux kernel version 6.6.23-v8-16k+.
My distributor is Debian GNU/Linux 121 (bookworm).
I am wanting to install and test the base xilinx_can module available in the base kernel code.
When installing the kernel, I was able to find to portion in the Configuration to tell the kernel installer to build this driver.
In the menuconfig, when building a Linux kernel, there is an option to have it build the Xilinx Can drvier for you
It appears that the Linux kernel has built the driver properly, as I can find the xilinx_can.ko module file in the drivers portion of my kernel code. However, when I try to install it, I receive the following errors when using insmod:
[  158.547832] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_put_echo_skb (err -2)
[  158.547855] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_get_echo_skb (err -2)
[  158.547871] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol alloc_canfd_skb (err -2)
[  158.547896] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol open_candev (err -2)
[  158.547912] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol of_can_transceiver (err -2)
[  158.547930] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol alloc_can_skb (err -2)
[  158.547944] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol unregister_candev (err -2)
[  158.547955] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_change_state (err -2)
[  158.547965] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_change_mtu (err -2)
[  158.547975] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_dropped_invalid_skb (err -2)
[  158.547988] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol free_candev (err -2)
[  158.547999] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol alloc_candev_mqs (err -2)
[  158.548011] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_fd_len2dlc (err -2)
[  158.548029] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_fd_dlc2len (err -2)
[  158.548044] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol close_candev (err -2)
[  158.548055] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol can_bus_off (err -2)
[  158.548083] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol alloc_can_err_skb (err -2)
[  158.548099] xilinx_can: Unknown symbol register_candev (err -2)


And when using modprobe:
modprobe: FATAL: Module xilinx_can not found in directory /lib/modules/6.6.23-v8-16k+


It seems that the kernel is missing some dependencies that the driver is expecting, but that feels odd since I did not edit or change any of the code, I merely told the kernel to build it.
Did I miss a box I needed to check when using menuconfig in the kernel builder? Or is it possible I didn't install the kernel properly, which is why it might be showing up as built in my kernel code but not appearing in lib/modules?
Thanks.

You need to get kernel source code via apt source linux… (I don’t remember package name by heart) and enable it there, and recompile kernel.

insmod does not automatically load dependencies of the requested module, so you need to load the "can-dev" module first.
